# Ruby installation issues with RVM

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, ruby, rvm, osx-yosemite

I've been following the directions at http://installrails.com to get my Macbook Air setup for some ruby work but I am running in any issue with RVM. When I try to install Ruby I get the following errors. I also see them when trying to run `ruby -v`.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgmp.10.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/Chris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby
  Reason: image not found
```

Googling around hasn't solved it, so I am confused what is causing it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I had the exact same problem when setting up RVM on my new Mac this morning:

```
$ ruby -v
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgmp.10.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/psoshnin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby
Reason: image not found
```

To solve the issue I first ran:

```
$ brew update && brew upgrade
```

Then I ran:

```
$ rvm reinstall 2.1.3 --disable-binary
```

And it installed successfully for me.

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.3p242 (2014-09-19 revision 47630) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh you are a champion! :D Now if only it made sense why it was being silly...

Comment: I didn't want to upgrade my various packages for this single issue, so I just ran: brew update && brew install gmp && rvm reinstall 2.1.3

Comment: I didn't have gmp installed. So the comment from @LeeXGreen worked best for me: `brew update && brew install gmp && rvm reinstall 2.1.3`

Comment: --disable-binary saved my day!! Thx!

Comment: @LeeXGreen, please add an answer so we can upvote :)

Comment: This answer is valid for OS X Yosemite as well. I got away with following @LeeXGreen's answer but didn't need to run `rum reinstall 2.1.3`...YMMV.

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me:

```
brew update && brew install gmp && rvm reinstall 2.1.3
```

Comment: Thx. It's working.